# Migrating IBM StartupBean EJB1.1 to @Startup EJB3.1

Tags: java, websphere, ejb-3.1

We are migrating 1.1 StartUp bean which previously used IBM interfaces:

```
<session id="StartUp">
    <ejb-name>StartUp</ejb-name>
    <home>com.ibm.websphere.startupservice.AppStartUpHome</home>
    <remote>com.ibm.websphere.startupservice.AppStartUp</remote>
    <ejb-class>org.bean.StartUpBean</ejb-class>
    <session-type>Stateful</session-type>
    <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
</session>
```

to EJB 3.1 standard. So far we wrote code for bean without usage of IBM propertialy implementation:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartUpBean{

@PostConstruct
    public void start() {
       ...
       helper.runHelper(); // in new class
     }
   }
```

At first we had problems with deployment order, because StartupBean was starting immediately after module. We solved that using different order in application.xml. However one problem still remains.

In helper method called from start method of this bean we have some code that lookups stateless 1.1 bean using JNDI name. That bean creates new entity bean (1.1) invoking method create in new transaction (using reguires_new in xml descriptor). Then it should commit that transaction in order to persist that entity and calls finder which search that record in database. It looks like:

```
void runHelper(){
   ... 
   oldRemote = Server.lookup(OldBean.JNDI, OldBean.class);
   oldBean.prepareApp(); //prepareApp has requires new transaction attribute
   findThatNewEntity(key); // FinderException (not in database)
}
```

And in old stateless bean 1.1

```
void prepareApp(){
 entityHome = Server.lookup(JNDI_NAME, Data.class);
 entityHome.create(key, value, value2);
}
```

I am 100 % sure, that in previous version of StartUp bean that was using IBM interfaces, entity was created and stored. Now it is not. I am affraid that transactions aren't somewhat supported at point whe application is starting. Is it so? Or is there any way how to force using transactions or some kind of workaround? Thank you.

Comment: All EJB method calls must support transaction settings, regardless whether made during an @Startup postconstruct or not. Can you double check your transaction attribute setting of prepareApp, and ensure it is not defaulting to REQUIRED.  Also verify that the key on the find is the same as on the create.